# Changing Gem Version of Compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I updated my version of compass and it broke other dependencies for a project. Can some please prove the command line code to role back to Compass 0.12.6?

I did spend time Googling this before posting to Stack, but came up empty handed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh ...

$ gem list
$ sudo gem uninstall compass
Then choose the version you want to remove. All versions of gems are still available on your machine.